# Two activities or two fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In an Android app, I have two screens* the user sees, one for preparing a query and the other for displaying the results. The right UI here is to have the query preparation in one screen, and then see the result on the second screen. Since this app is aimed at phone users, there's no need to display the two at once.

The traditional Android way is to use two activities, a `QueryPreparationActivity` and a `DisplayResultActivity`, and switch between the two. However, I've been hearing more and more about how the Android UI is switching to fragments. I can implement the two screens as two fragments and have the activity switch them, but is it worth the trouble? I will essentially be reproducing the Activity management code Android already has.

Is there a reason to use two fragments here?

<sub>*I'm using the term `screen`, because it isn't necessarily an activity...</sub>

Comment: Thank you all. You're all saying the same thing, and you've convinced me to spend the extra time, do the extra work and implement the UI with fragments. I can't accept all your answers, so the person with the least credit gets the checkmark...

Comment: why did you choose ebarrencheas answer when I answered first?

Comment: i was just asking to see how I could improve my answer and why he chose ebarrenchea. We give the same points and reasons..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fragments were introduced encapsulate UI elements and related behaviour into a single, reusable module. Before fragments you had to re-write the much of the same code that 2 or more activities had in common especially if you couldn't find a good approach to abstract the UI/control code into a super class. This was further complicated by the limitations that activities only call `setContentView` once. So sharing some code between activities wasn't all that nice.

Now, to answer your question, it all depends on you. If you think that further down the road you could use the QueryPreparation or DisplayResult ui as a module (layout and logic behind it) then go for the fragment implementation. It could be a different layout for landscape view on phone or if you decide to support smaller tablets like the nexus 7. If you are sure that it will never happen then stick with activities. Personally, I use fragments everywhere and they are a sure way to "future proof" your implementation for reuse down the road.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I always develop using Fragments.

But the best reason I can give you for using Fragments is when you develop for handset and tablet devices you get a lot of reusability.

I know you already mentioned that there is no need to show both screens at once. But say later you were to develop the same "screen" for a tablet device and realize that the preparation screen is too barren and want to have both queryprep and display result show at the same time, you would have to write a totally new 3rd activity.

If you used fragments, you would reuse your 1 activity and 2 fragments, and that activity should be coded smart enough to determine the size of the screen and show the proper layout.

Code Reusability & Flexibility are the buzz words here.

If you have any questions please leave a comment and I will expand my answer. If you like my answer, please upvote and accept.

Comment: Give some best example for Details Fragment, I want to use for creating profiles like activity.

Answer (score 1):

In short Fragments were introduced to accommodate the emergence of tablet/large screen devices   and allow developers to create applications that will run across a wide range of screen sizes with very little change to code.

More can be [read here at the Android Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html). That blog also details some of the finer technical details for the reasons for the move toward Fragments. Also introduced at Goolge IO 2012 were DialogFragments which you should consider using instead of Dialogs. Another blog post [here describes](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html) them.

You're better off getting used to using Fragments and DialogFragments from the get go as this is the way Android is moving. Only use individual Activities if you really really need to do a quick-and-dirty app for say testing purposes. Fragments, in my opinion, do require a bit more code-work to incorporate and to initially get your head round but it's worth the effort.